# How to avoid clang-tidy warning when passing shared_ptr to thread function?

Tags: c++, multithreading, warnings, clang-tidy, pass-by-const-reference

I have C++ code that looks (simplified) like this:

```cpp
#include <unistd.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

std::thread the_thread;

void my_thread_func(const std::shared_ptr<std::string>& string_ptr) {
    std::cout << "at thread begin: " << *string_ptr << std::endl;
    sleep(1);
    std::cout << "at thread finish: " << *string_ptr << std::endl;
}

void start_thread() {
    auto local_string_ptr = std::make_shared<std::string>("foobar");
    the_thread = std::thread(&my_thread_func, local_string_ptr);
}

int main(int, char**) {
    start_thread();
    sleep(2);
    the_thread.join();
}
```

(on Compiler Explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/9GYTf7orz)

When I run `clang-tidy --checks=performance-unnecessary-value-param` for this code, it warns:

```
<source>:10:50: warning: the parameter 'string_ptr' is copied for each invocation but only used as a const reference; consider making it a const reference [performance-unnecessary-value-param]
   10 | void my_thread_func(std::shared_ptr<std::string> string_ptr) {
```

But my understanding is that passing `string_ptr` as const reference to `my_thread_func()` would be incorrect, since then the thread would have a reference to an object that is local to `start_thread()` and that is destroyed while the thread is running.

My questions:

- would it be correct (and recommended) to use `void my_thread_func(const std::shared_ptr<std::string>& string_ptr)`, or would that be an error?
- is the clang-tidy warning correct, or is it a false positive?
- is my code generally incorrect/inelegant, thereby causing this problem this problem in the first place? I.e. what would be the best way to write this?

My experience is that clang-tidy is usually correct :-) that's why I'm confused about the warning here.

Comment: If you want to pass a reference use [`std::ref` or `std::cref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref). But you don't want to do that (passing a reference to a local variable which will immediately have its life-time end). Instead you want to pass the shared pointer *by value*, i.e. without the reference `&` in the function declaration. That is what makes the shared pointer actually shared. And with that said, why do you need a pointer to a string to begin with? Pointers to containers (arrays, vectors, strings and others) are seldom needed.

Comment: Use lambda expressions to start your thread e.g. `std::thread( [local_string_ptr]{ my_threadfunc(local_string_ptr); }`. This way you explicitly capture local_string_ptr by value and a copy is made

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the reason for this code is that I want to create the string in `start_thread()` but want to use it in the thread afterwards (and in my real code it's not just a string but a custom object, but that should not matter here, right?). Is there some better way to write this use case (creating the large-ish object in `start_thread()` and then passing it to the thread)?

Comment: Then just pass the shared pointer by value. That will make a copy of the shared pointer object, but not the actual object it points to. That's the nature of shared pointers, you can have many copies of the pointer, but only one single data object. Passing references to smart pointers seldom makes sense, and in some cases is even counter-productive.

Comment: `shared_ptr` is meant to be passed around by value: `void my_thread_func(const std::shared_ptr<std::string>& string_ptr)` -> `void my_thread_func(std::shared_ptr<std::string> string_ptr)`

Comment: *"I want to create the string in start_thread() but want to use it in the thread afterwards"*. Since the object is not guarded by any synchronization object, you will face a race and end up with UB. If  outcome of the thread is set only once(analogous to `return`), use the `std::promise` + `std::future` duo. Otherwise, rethink your sync scheme.

Comment: I can't replicate that warnings, but getting other `error: do not use 'std::endl' with streams; use '\n' instead`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clang-tidy warning assumes a **single-threaded** context: an ordinary call to a function

```
int get(std::shared_ptr<int> p,std::binary_semaphore &s) {
  s.acquire();
  return *p;
}
```

might very well need the `std::shared_ptr` parameter (object, not reference) to keep the `int` alive long enough to return it.  (The caller might have obtained a reference to the `std::shared_ptr` from some table rather than constructing it for the call, and whatever signals the semaphore might drop the only other reference immediately after doing so.)

Separately, even if the function called for a thread has a reference **parameter**, it will not be a reference to an argument to the `std::thread` constructor: each such argument is copied into a temporary *T* whose lifetime is that of the thread, and the reference refers to *T*.  (As mentioned in the comments, you can use `std::ref` to produce a `std::reference_wrapper` that can convert back into a reference to the original argument.)  That means that you might not need a `std::shared_ptr` here at all: you can just construct the object as an argument, and it will be moved into *T*.

Comment: "each such argument is copied into a temporary T whose lifetime is that of the thread, and the reference refers to T.". Interesting! Is that a behaviour that is specific to `std::thread()`?

Comment: @oliver: I’m not sure which alternative to `std::thread` you have in mind (`std::jthread` does the same thing), but it’s pretty sensible since of course the constructor will in general return long before the thread finishes.